# Is there a way to give a website information, and get a plot back?

Tags: c#

I am currently programming a program that solves  a quadratic equation in c# windows forms. Is there a way for me to give a site that can plot, like GeoGebra, and get a picture of the plot back?

Comment: Why don't you use some kind of plotting library for C#, like this, for example: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any easy way of getting the picture from such a website.

If you are ok with embedding a browser window into your form (there are components for that) you can use [the Desmos API.](https://www.desmos.com/api/v1.4/docs/index.html) **Quick Start** will give you a taste of how it should work.

It shouldn't be too hard to do.